# Scroll al hacer foco en un Componente X JAVA

Tags: java, android

Me encuentro con el siguiente dilema supongamos que tengo un control en este caso un `EditText` y por debajo tengo un  `Button` el cual me permite seguir el curso de la app ,

Ahora mi problema es que quiero que cuando se haga foco o se cliquee el `EditText`
mi app haga un scroll hacia abajo para poder permitir ver el boton al final , para no tener que sacar el teclado para darle al boton , dejo un flujo de imagenes para que se entienda mas claro

**Ejemplo 1**:

Me pongo sobre el correo electronico ,al hacer esto aparecera el teclado ocultandome el boton que esta por detras ,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaria  es que al poner para escribir el correo automaticamente se haga un scroll hacia arriba , cosa de poder vizualizar el boton de continuar mientras escribo , esto solo por comidad del usuario , desde ya gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

XML DE VISTA

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtCorreo"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/T14"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorRayaEditText"
            android:textColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"/>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:onClick="GoToRegistryStep2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorFondoHomeAzulado"
                android:text="@string/Continuar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/iconodeaceptar"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/T14"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Metodos que intente hasta ahora

```
EditText txtCorreo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
    txtCorreo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
               final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
                sv.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        sv.fullScroll(sv.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Y tambien intente

```
 txtCorreo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
                sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

preferiblemente algo que me sirva desde 4.1 Version en adelante

Le agrege en el manifest la propiedad

```
 <activity android:name="banred.twoinnovateit.com.bimo_new.RegistroStep1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >

    </activity>
```

pero aun asi el teclado me oculta mi boton

Comment: Agrega el xml de la vista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues creo que tengo una buena respuesta.
Primeramente tengo mi Layout 'activity_main.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
    android:text="Texto"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Mi Botón"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

---

Ahora en el MainActivity inicializo mis Widgets.

```
scrollView - editText - textView - button
```

---

Establecemos un `listener` para el editText

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                //almacenamos aquí el dispositivo que estamos utilizando para introducir información.
                InputMethodManager miTeclado = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //establecemos un scroll en pantalla
                scrollView.scrollTo(20, 300);
                //Ocultamos el teclado
                miTeclado.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    });
```

Ahí le hemos dado un scroll a la pantalla cuando no tengamos el Foco en el EditText.

---

Extra. Quitar el Foco cuando se presiona el Enter del Teclado.
Creamos una clase interna en el MainActivity que realiza ese trabajo.

```
class EventoTeclado implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){ //Si se ha ocultado el teclado porque hemos pulsado el ok
            editText.clearFocus();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Nos vamos al `onCreate` de nuestra `MainActivity` y instanciamos esta clase.

```
EventoTeclado eventoTeclado = new EventoTeclado();
```

Ponemos a la escucha nuestro editText para que tenga efecto.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(eventoTeclado);
```

---

**Añado nuevo método para obtener la posicion del botón**

```
private Point obtenerPosicionDeLaVista(View view){
        int[] localizaccion = new int[2];
        view.getLocationInWindow(localizaccion);
        return new Point(localizaccion[0], localizaccion[1]);
    }
```

---

*Y ahora lo mando a llamar...*

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                //almacenamos aquí el dispositivo que estamos utilizando para introducir información.
                InputMethodManager miTeclado = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //establecemos un scroll en pantalla
                Point point = obtenerPosicionDeLaVista(button);
                scrollView.scrollTo(point.x, point.y);
                //Ocultamos el teclado
                miTeclado.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    });
```

> P.d. Eso es todo amigos :)

Comment: lo intente Diego pero sin exito , el scroll me tapa aun mas envez de hacer aparecer el teclado

Comment: Realmente puse unas posiciones orientativas, cambia los 300 en el paso de argumentos 'es el que nos interesa ya que pertenece al eje y', y cambialo por el que mejor te venga a ti (button.getButton()-50) o algo así. Saludos!

Comment: si no te molestaria , el primer parametro es x y el otro y? en otras palabras el x es el ancho y la y la altura no entiendo bien

Comment: A la hora de hacer scroll se dirige a esa zona de la pantalla. Es la localización de la pantalla en el eje x 'a lo que tu llamas width' y el eje y 'la altura'. Voy a modificar o añadir unas líneas que te llevarán a la posición exacta de tu botón.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega esto en el xml de tu manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Lo anterior funciona si hay suficiente espacio que "reducir". De lo contrario prueba con el siguiente código que en ontouch en el último ediText hace un scroll hacia abajo:

```
tuUltimoEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
            {
                ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
                sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
                return false;
            }
        });
```

En el xml todos los views deben estar dentro del relative ó linearlayout y este a su vez de ScrollView

Comment: agregandole esto no hace nada nose si me faltaria algo mas

Comment: una disculpa, revisando mi respuesta, eso es en el manifest de tu activity, y esto funciona siempre y cuando haya suficiente espacio en el layout

Comment: y hay mas opciones para el teclado https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft .Tambien en: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard

Comment: Realizando unicamente esto no funciona a menos que el boton este abajo del EditText

Comment: el boton si esta abajo @Jorgesys pero aun asi no funciona ?

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Se supone que el teclado contextual se muestra debajo de la vista que tiene el enfoque, en este caso si lo activas mediante el primer EditText el botón esta muy abajo de esta vista.

Comment: @Jorgesys en mi xml perdon omite los demas edittexts , tengo muchos esos de la pregunta son los ultimos 2 , para tener una idea los editestxs ocupan todo el largo de la pantalla

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer esto, tienes que darle un id al ScrollView y luego llamar al método scroll del ScrollView.

Estas es la definición del método scroll:

```
scrollTo(int x, int y)
Set the scrolled position of your view.

This version also clamps the scrolling to the bounds of our child.
```

Esta información está obtenida de: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Si lo que quieres es desplazarlo hasta "abajo", tendrías que llamar al método de la siguiente manera:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
```

Esta respuesta está sacada de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438061/can-i-scroll-a-scrollview-programmatically-in-android

Comment: como se puede ver en la publicación , tengo que cuando hagan foco se realize este código , pero aun asi no se desplaza aunque lo mirare mas a fondo , gracias Pablo por tu ayuda!

Comment: Asegúrate que utilizas un ScrollView que tiene que contener los botones, edittext..., si te da algún error comenta lo que te pasa

Comment: revise varias veces esto pero sin ningun tipo de exito